# Extracting bits of data to make an Excel graph

Tags: vba, excel

I have several columns populated with data and they have headings as follows:

```
RP hEPO Gradient Elution Optimization004:10_Cond
RP hEPO Gradient Elution Optimization004:10_pH
RP hEPO Gradient Elution Optimization004:10_Pressure
```

This is raw data and I am not creating these titles. I am interested in the last bit of it: Cond, pH, and Pressure. I want to create a graph with conductivity, pH and pressure and I want my program to be able to identify the correct column for the plot labels.  Is there a way to search for "Cond" within that cell so I can use it in an `if` function or something?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - your possible duplicate is written in [tag:C#]. That said, there is surely a duplicate VBA question on SO. OP - see `Find` excel formula. No need for VBA for this at all.

Comment: it seems that all of the string preceeding the part of your interest is constant and always the same ... so you may want to use the search/replace function to search for that constant part and replace it by an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking part after the underscore try this bit of code:

```
 Sub Macro1()
     mystring = Cells(1, 1)
     mytitle = Right(mystring, Len(mystring) - InStr(mystring, "_"))
 End Sub
```

This will extract the part of the string after the dash.  Be careful the InStr function will return 0 if the the "_" is not found in the original string.  I will let you modify the cell reference and the error checking.

To use this function in the worksheet and not in the VBA function replace the "InStr" with the "FIND" function.  This is one of the mismatches between the workbook and VBA.